# Is a deobfuscated version of chat js available?

Tags: support, chat

The dev portion of the CDN hosts unminified JS for the main SE sites (you can find it via http://dev.stackoverflow.com ). However, I can't seem to find the same for chat.

Is there any link for unminified chat js?

Comment: I don't think so, but obviously I can't be certain.